# IP address with different country

Tags: geolocation, ip

We are using IP geolocation vendor in our application. And vendor will update their database in monthly basis.

But IP address is getting assigned to different country over time. Any proper reference or standard for this changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a geofeed file and host it in your website. The format is based on [RFC 8805](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8805).

However, it is still up to the geolocation vendor to trust your feed and take into records. IP geolocation is under heavily manipulation due to many reasons.